# Converting letter position in the alphabet to numbers in C#

Tags: c#, count, alphabet

I need to convert letters into numbers. The A would be 01, the B would be 02 ... Z would be 26.

My pseudocode:

```
variable = 'C'

if (variable = 'A'){
counter = 01}else if (variable = 'B'){
counter = 02}else if (variable = 'C'){
counter = 03
}elseif...
```

There sure must be another way to do this.

Comment: Try `variable - 'A'`, although you should probably validate that `variable` is in the right range...

Comment: Literally 01?  You need the zero?

Comment: Do we need to deal with accents, upper lower case and the like?

Comment: You do realize there are 101,013 letters (and that's without combining them with additional accents, etc.)? See [Char.IsLetter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zff1at55(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try:

```
var x = 'A' - 'A' + 1 //01
var x = 'Z' - 'A' + 1 //26
```

Answer (score 5):

If those letters are all uppercase ASCII letters you can easily do it like this:

```
int ascii = (int)Char.GetNumericValue(variable);
if(ascii >= 65 && ascii <= 90)
{
    counter = ascii - 64;
}
else if //...
```

Answer (score 4):

Each character has its own ascii code where for example "A" starts at 65 so basically you can just subtract 64 from each character and you get your number.
"A" - 64 = 1
"B" - 64 = 2...

Answer (score 2):

```
int charToDigit(char character){
    return character-64; //or character-0x40 if you prefer hex
}
```

This will simply convert the ASCII char to its corresponding int and pull it down to 1.

Since 'A' is 65 or 0x41 in ASCII, it will result in a 1 when subtracting 64./0x40. Subtract 0x40 if you want 'A' to be 0.

Answer (score 1):

```
private String Number2String(int number, bool isCaps)
{
    Char c = (Char)((isCaps ? 65 : 97) + (number - 1));
    return c.ToString();
}
```